# drawing loop curve in jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart

I wanna to draw a loop curve in jfreechart like this:

[image]

I try to draw this by XYPlot, but when the direction changes, the points is overlapped and the figure fails.

for example if we start drawing at point D (Or C), the points will be overlapped after A and the figure broke down.

Note that the input data dynamically is read from a source.

Comment: Try an [`XYShapeAnnotation`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20XYShapeAnnotation).

Comment: Thanks @eric, using  `series = new XYSeries("name",false);` instead of `series = new XYSeries("name");` seems to be work.